# Animating Show and Hide views in tabpanel - Ext JS

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I am using ExtJS 6.0.1. I have my view port with center and east region configured with Ext.tab.Panel. I use a button to show and hide the center and north region. I could do that perfectly with show() and hide() methods. Is there a way to animate the view by sliding in any direction

```js
xtype      : 'app-main',
    controller : 'main',
    viewModel  : {
        type: 'main'
    },
    layout     : {
        type: 'border'
    },
    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me,{
            items   : [{
            region      : 'center',
            xtype       : 'layoutP1',
            split       : true,            
            flex        : 1
        },{
            region      : 'east',
            xtype       : 'layoutP2',
            layout      : 'fit',
            split       : true,
            hidden      : true,
            flex        : 1
        }]
     });
```

I use a button at the footer to show/hide the panel in center and east region

```js
onClickP1: function() {
        this.getP2layout().flex = 2000;
        this.getP1layout().show();
        this.getP2.hide();
    },
onClickP2View: function() {
        this.getP2layout().flex = 2000;
        this.getP1layout().flex = 2000;
        this.getP1layout().hide();
        this.getP2layout().show();
    }
```

With this I can able to show and hide the panel but i need to animate sliding from left to right /right to left based on the region.

And is there a way to do the same using Splitters?. I can see Panel by default it comes with splitter to collapse and expand the panel.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use [`slideIn`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.dom.CompositeElementLite.html#method-slideIn) on `dom` element (`panel/veiw`).

**slideIn** slides the element into view. An anchor point can be optionally passed to set the point of origin for the slide effect. This function automatically handles wrapping the element with a fixed-size container if needed. See the [`Ext.fx.Anim`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.fx.Anim.html) class overview for valid anchor point options.

Usage:

```
// default: slide the element in from the top
el.slideIn();

// custom: slide the element in from the left with a 2-second duration
el.slideIn('l', { duration: 2000 });

// common config options shown with default values
el.slideIn('r', {
    easing: 'easeOut',
    duration: 500
});
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bbv)**, I have created a demo. I hope this will guide you to achieve your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    height: window.innerHeight,
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [{
        title: 'Border Layout',
        layout: 'border',
        items: [{
            title: 'Center Region',
            region: 'center', // center region is required, no width/height specified
            xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'p1',
            layout: 'fit',
            split: true
        }, {
            // xtype: 'panel' implied by default
            title: 'East Region is collapsible',
            layout: 'fit',
            region: 'east',
            itemId: 'p2',
            xtype: 'panel',
            split: true,
            hidden: true
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'P1',
            disabled: true,
            handler: function () {
                this.up('tabpanel').doHideShow(this)
            }
        }, {
            text: 'P2',
            handler: function () {
                this.up('tabpanel').doHideShow(this)
            }
        }]
    }],

    //For hide/show view on basis of button click P1/P2
    doHideShow: function (btn) {
        btn.setDisabled(true);
        if (btn.getText() == 'P1') {
            this.down('#p1').show().setWidth('100%').getEl().slideIn('l');
            this.down('#p2').hide();
            this.down('[text=P2]').setDisabled(false);
        } else {
            this.down('#p2').show().setWidth('100%').getEl().slideIn('r');
            this.down('#p1').hide();
            this.down('[text=P1]').setDisabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```